# Subgroups of index $p^2$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^\times\ltimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, semidirect-product

I want to prove that the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^\times\ltimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique subgroup of index $p^2$.

I know that $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$, hence by the Chinese remainder theorem isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$, but this doesn't seem to get me much further.

My teacher sees this as a triviality, but I don't seem to see it.. Could someone provide any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your group is $p^2(p-1)$, so every subgroup of index $p^2$ has order $p-1$. For $p=2$ the claim is clearly true as any group has a unique subgroup of order $1$. So suppose $p>2$.

Let $a\in(\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ and $b\in\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. Computing powers of $(a,b)$ shows that
$$(a,b)^2=(a^2,b(a+1)),\qquad (a,b)^3=(a^3,b(a^2+a+1)),$$
and in general, if $a\neq1$, for any positive integer $k$ we have
$$(a,b)^k=\Big(a^k,b\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a^k\Big)=\Big(a^k,b\tfrac{a^k-1}{a-1}\Big).\tag{1}$$
From this it easily follows that the order of $(a,b)$ equals the order of $a$.

Now pick some $a\in(\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ of order $p-1$ and pick any two distinct elements $b_1,b_2\in\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. Then the expression in $(1)$ makes it easy to verify that for all $k$ we have
$$(a,b_1)\neq(a,b_2)^k,$$
so $(a,b_1)$ and $(a,b_2)$ generate two *distinct* subgroups of order $p-1$.

Comment: Why is the order of an element $(a,b)$ for $b\neq 0$ a multiple of $p$? We are working with a semi-direct product with law $(x,y)(x',y')=(xx',xy'+y)$.

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz Ah, I had read the semi-direct product the other way around, with $\rtimes$ instead of $\ltimes$. In that case the claim is false for $p>2$; I have updated my answer.